# Unterschied zwischen "beschimpfen" und "beleidigen"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, verb

Wie seht Ihr den Unterschied zwischen "beschimpfen" und "beleidigen", wenn es überhaupt einen gibt? [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/beschimpfen) sagt, dass "beschimpfen" "mit groben Worten schmähen, beleidigen" bedeutet; [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/beschimpfen) behauptet, dass es "jmdn. durch Schmähungen beleidigen" ist. Ich bin kein Muttersprachler und nehme an, dass es teilweise um die Absichtlichkeit der Beleidigung/Beschimpfung geht, aber bin mir nicht sicher. Wenn ich Unrecht habe und es nur einen zarten Unterschied gibt, kann ich ihn nicht bemerken — vielleicht könntet Ihr Beispiele dafür geben?

Comment: NB, die angegebene Definition von "beschimpfen" umfasst *mit groben Worten*, also auf jeden Fall eine verbale Äußerung. Man kann jmd. aber auch ohne Äußerung beleidigen, etwa indem man ein erwartetes Höflichkeitsverhalten unterlässt.

Answer (score 2):

Laut [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/schimpfen) bedeutet "schimpfen"

> über jemanden/etwas laut durch Worte seinen Unwillen äußern, heftig schelten.

Bevor man also beginnt, zirkulär zu argumentieren (wie etwa @Alina in einem Kommentar), daß eine Rüge keine Beschimpfung sein kann, weil dann das Rügen ein Beschimpfen konstituieren würde - *und das sehe ich anders* (die Logik muß man erstmal verstehen: "Gravitation" und "Schwerkraft" können unmöglich das Gleiche sein, weil sonst ja Schwerkraft und Gravitation identisch wären - und das sehe ich anders) - sollte man vielleicht zuerst versuchen, verschiedene Begriffe gegeneinander abzugrenzen.

Folgende Worte fallen mir auf die Schnelle ein, die ähnliche Tätigkeiten bzw. Vorgänge beschreiben: schelten, rügen, kränken, (ver-)höhnen, (ver-)spotten

"schelten" und "rügen" sind vermutlich noch am ehesten Synonyme für "schimpfen", denn auch sie bringen Unwillen zum Ausdruck, in der Regel über jemandes Verhalten. "Schimpfen", im Gegensatz zu diesen, kann auch gänzlich unpersönlich adressiert sein: schimpfen kann man über das schlechte Wetter, das Fernsehprogramm oder ähnliches. Es mag natürlich sein, daß das Schimpfen über das Fernsehprogramm die Schelte (oder auch die Rüge) für den Programmgestalter beinhaltet - aber das muß nicht notwendigerweise der Fall sein.

> Die alten Leute schimpften, als das Büffet von sieben Uhr auf neun verlegt wurde.

Dieses Zusammenfallen von "schimpfen" und "schelten" oder "rügen" ist es auch - ungeachtet Alinas Sichtweise - das die Anwendung des Schimpfens in der Kindererziehung möglich macht: ohne dem Kind eine - hier negative - Rückmeldung zu seinem Verhalten zu geben (genau das ist eine Rüge, was man eben auch als "mit dem Kind schimpfen" bezeichnet) wird dieses schwerlich verstehen, was eigentlich an Verhalten von ihm erwartet wird.

Was nun ist der Unterschied zwischen "schimpfen" und "beleidigen"?

Zunächst zur Klarstellung: die Bedeutung "jemand mit einer kränkenden Bezeichnung versehen" wird umgangssprachlich auch "schimpfen" genannt:

> Der hat mich als Dieb beschimpft.

Die **Beleidigung** beinhaltet immer eine - wenigstens intendierte - Kränkung, nicht notwendigerweise aber auch eine Beschimpfung. Vielleicht ist der als "Dieb" apostrophierte tatsächlich ein Dieb, dann könnte das immer noch eine Beleidigung sein (wenn es nämlich als solche gemeint war - in der Sprache ist Kontext alles!), selbst dann, wenn die Bezeichnung faktisch korrekt ist. Man kann aber auch beleidigen (d.h. etwas sagen, was den anderen kränken soll), ohne zu schimpfen (d.h. seinen Unwillen zu äußern):

> Wofür halten sie mich?
> Ich halte sie für genau das, was sie sind!

Das ist offensichtlich beleidigend gemeint, ohne irgendeine Beschimpfung zu äußern.

Wie man sieht, gibt es Beschimpfungen ohne Beleidigung, Beleidigungen ohne Beschimpfung, aber die Schnittmenge, wo sowohl das eine wie auch das andere vorliegt, ist groß. Dennoch ist etwa die [Publikumsbeschimpfung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publikumsbeschimpfung) Peter Handkes keine Beleidigung (wenigstens keine des Publikums - schon eher eine der Intelligenz, aber das nur nebenbei).

Answer (score 0):

Eine *Beleidigung* ist eine Äußerung, die das Ziel hat, eine Person in ihrer Ehre zu verletzen.

Eine *Beschimpfung* beinhaltet immer auch eine Beleidigung. Üblicherweise spricht man aber von einer Beschimpfung erst dann, wenn es sich um eine ausgedehnte, umfangreiche Äußerung handelt, die auch mehrere beleidigende Sprechakte beinhaltet, um eine [*Tirade*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirade).

Beispiele für diese Verwendungsweise sind der Titel des Dramas *Publikumsbeschimpfung* von Peter Handke, oder auch die Worte *Schimpftirade*, *Schimpfkannonade*.

Vorsicht ist geboten beim Verb *schimpfen*. Das Verb *schimpfen* hat "beschimpfen" als Zweitbedeutung. Die Hauptbedeutung von *schimpfen* ist allerdings "tadeln, schelten, zurechtweisen", insbesondere von Eltern gegenüber einem Kind.

Answer (score 0):

Die deutsche Vorsilbe "be-" bedeutet eigentlich "etwas/jemanden einer Tätigkeit unterziehen" - und die Tätigkeit findet sich im Verbstamm.

"jemanden beschimpfen" bedeutet damit wörtlich "ihn der Tätigkeit des Schimpfens unterziehen", und *könnte* damit einfach nur bedeuten, dass man jemanden (wie z.B. ein Kind, dass man erzieht) heftig tadelt. Nur wird das Verb in diesem Sinne nicht (oder nicht mehr?) verwendet.

*Beschimpfen* wird gängigerweise nur für wahre Schimpftiraden verwendet. Es sind immer beleidigende und sozial unangebrachte Ausdrücke und Angriffe im Spiel, und es wird impliziert, dass der Beschimpfende dafür in Rage gerät und die Kontrolle über sich verliert. Lautstärke und Redeschwall sind starke Anzeichen einer Beschimpfung. "Absicht" ist nicht ganz das richtige Wort dafür, ich sehe im "Beschimpfen" eher eine möglicherweise ungewollte Eskalation.

*Beleidigen* kann man auch leise, und möglicherweise ganz ohne Worte (jemanden zu ignorieren oder zu vergessen, kann ebenfalls eine Beleidigung darstellen). Verlust der Selbstkontrolle kann in selteneren Fällen, muss aber nicht Bestandteil der Beleidigung sein. Man kann auch jemanden sehr kalkuliert und in voller Absicht beleidigen.

Comment: Wenn sich ein Verkehrsteilnehmer erregt über das Fehlverhalten eines anderen mokiert, dann kann ich mir Beschimpfungen denken ("Sie müssen doch Vorfahrt geben, Sie müssen doch schauen ob jmd. kommt!") die nicht beleidigend sind und nicht sozial unangebracht.

Comment: @userunknown "Sie müssen doch..." ist in meinen Augen keine Beschimpfung. Wenn jemand jemanden beschimpft, werden i.A. sehr viel weiter gehende, unangebrachte Höflichkeiten ausgetauscht.

Answer (score -1):

Beschimpfen bedeutet, jemandem ein Schimpfwort zu sagen (unpersönlich).
Beleidigen bedeutet, jemanden zu versuchen mit seinen Worten zu verletzen (persönlich).

Comment: Nein, es ist genau andersherum.

Comment: @Janka nein eigentlich nicht, denn das wort heißt sogar: beschimpfen -> Schimpfwort, mit jemand schimpfen beleidigen -> jemand leidet darunter

Comment: @Xyndra, das ist nicht unbedingt richtig, denn es gibt noch andere Wortstämme, die hier naheliegen, etwa den von *Lied*, *liederlich*, *leiern* oder *legen* (mundartlich *belejen*, ebenso kann d elidiert werden, *jemannen beleiien*), die hier naheliegen dürften. Flüche, um jmd. damit zu *belegen*, können besonders kunstvoll ausgearbeitet sein, zb. Böhmermanns Schmähgedicht auf Erdogan, oder einfacher, "liar liar, pants in fire", daher der Bezug auf's Lied, der bereits Umdeutung erfahren haben dürfte, als althochdeutsch "*leidigōn* ‘Leid zufügen, betrüben, verwirren’ (um 1000)" (DWDS) entstand.

Answer (score -1):

Man kann jemanden (be)schimpfen ohne die Person zu beleidigen.

Eine Beleidigung bedeutet eine Person herabzusetzen und (mindestens teilweise) Würde und Ehre abzusprechen. (Be)Schimpfen kann man eine Person ohne sie gleich herabzusetzen.

"Boah, da musst Du doch aufpassen! Die Regeln sind doch so, dass X immer einzuhalten ist - und dann übersieht man Y auch nicht...!" etc. Da habe ich die Person noch nicht beleidigt sondern nur geschimpft bzw. die Person beschimpft. Wenn ich jetzt noch Schmähworte hinzufüge, dann wird es auch beleidigend.

Comment: Ich glaube, du nimmst *beschimpfen* ein bißchen zu wörtlich. Es bedeutet explizit *nicht*, "jemanden ausschimpfen"

Comment: Inwiefern ist eine Aufforderung aufzupassen, der man Allgemeinplätze über Regeln folgen lässt, eine Beschimpfung? Wenn das eine Beschimpfung wäre, wäre ja jede Rüge und jede Zurechtweisung eine Beschimpfung. Dann wäre das Erziehen von Kindern nur möglich, wenn man die Kinder beschimpft. Das sehe ich anders.

Comment: Und wieso sollte es keine Beschimpfung sein? Du nennst kein Argument, wieso das Schimpfen auf jmd. der anwesend ist nicht Beschimpfen genannt werden soll. Das Erziehen von Kindern mag freilich ohne Beschimpfen möglich sein - das ist eine andere Frage. In der Praxis mag es schwierig sein ganz aufs Schimpfen zu verzichten.

Answer (score -1):

Ich glaube für das Verständnis ist maßgeblich, in welchem Register die Worte vorrangig Verwendung finden, insoweit es die prägende Phase des Spracherwerbs betrifft (s. *schimpfen*, *mit einem Kind*). In der Hochsprache mag das eine untergeordnete Rolle spielen, weil historische Einflüsse anders nachwirken, die gegebenenfalls erst im weiteren Verlauf des Lebens erworben werden. Es ist so zu unterscheiden nach Agens, Implikation und weiterem Kontext.

Um es mit @tofro zu halten, sei bzgl. der Vorsilbe *be-* auf zwei Phrasen verwiesen, die das bei-Wort ausdrücklich konnotieren:  *bei Schimpf und Schande* (heute geläufiger *mit, unter*) bzw. *Beileid*.

1. Früher stand wohl *Schimpf und Scherz*. Daraus ließe sich schließen, dass *Schande* in diesem Sinne zu *skandieren* zählt, insofern *chant* zu vermuten ist; s. dazu *scherzo* in der Musik.

   > dieweil uns uber disser sache, ja auch allen andern sachen, szo gott belangen, kein schimpf und schercz sundern ein gestrackter emsiger ernst ist. *schreiben des raths von Orlamünde an herzog Johann von Sachsen vom 12. sept. 1524 (Weimar, Ernest. ges.-arch.);* [DWB]

   Dies betrifft eine veraltete Bedeutung. Grimm unterscheided darauffolgend hauptsächlich zwei weitere Bedeutungsebenen. Das eine Beispiel passt zu meiner Vorrede:

   > bœs ernst kumt von bœsem schimphe:

   > man sol schimphen daʒ eʒ glimphe.

   > *Welsch. Gast 661* [DWB]

   Dies als Überleitung zu "boshafter scherz, spott, verhöhnung".

   Wichtiger scheint ihm zwar die "Kränkung":

   > *indem der begriff der kränkung den des scherzes völlig verdrängt, entwickelt sich aus der vorigen die heute allein übliche anwendung im allgemeinen sinne von* ehrverletzung, schmach, schande. ignominia. Frisch 2, 183ᵇ.

   Damit ist es bald synonym zu *Beleidigung*. Doch bestehen Unterschiede (3. a - f), vgl. bspw. c) "man dingte mich dazu
   schimpf anzuthun dem fürsten von Temim.", d) "schimpf *mit anderen dieser bedeutung verwandten ausdrücken verbunden*: sihe, wie du mich, mein frommes weib und arme kinderlein hast wöllen in schimpff und hohn und spott setzen."  e) "was härter treffe kränkung oder schimpf, will ich nicht untersuchen."—Es ist also sträflich, peinlich und verwerflich.

   Allerdings taucht "bei" darin nicht auf. Nur die Wendung *bei Strafe verboten* lässt einen Zusammenhang erahnen; vermutlich ist *pein* < mittellatein *pena* "Strafe, Buße, Höllenqual, ..." kein schlechter Ansatz (vgl. althochdeutsch *biscof*, kirchenlatein *episkopos*).

   Besonders interessant ist jedoch, dass nebenstehende Varianten wie "Schampf" einen Vergleich mit "Kampf", "champf" geradzu aufdrängen, den die Belege tatsächlich zulassen, s. u. 1. "Scherz" bspw. d) "ritterlicher schimpf, *kampfspiel, turnier*" e) "wendungen wie die folgenden, in denen auf einen wirklichen kampf bezug genommen wird:"

   > froun Jeschûten wart der gruoʒ

   > mit swertes schimpfe aldâ bejagt

   > mit heldes handen unverzagt.

   > *Parz. 263, 25;*

   Dementsprechend könnte man mit französisch *ex-, es-* auf *Herausforderung* "Provokation" verweisen. Der Vergleich erübrigt sich leider, insoweit die romanische Etymologie ins leere läuft und s-mobile unerklerlich bleibt.

   Außerdem könnte Jiddisch *schmusen* (engl. *to smooze*) in vielfältigen Bedeutungen relevant sein, gerade weil unter anderem daher *schm-* als Vorsilbe veralgemeinert wurde. Demnach dürfte "schmähen" im Wortlaut der Frage ebenso zweifelhaft sein. Rinse and repeat; Jiddisch-Schmiddisch, seisdrum.
2. Wie *sympathia*, *Pathos* gegenüber engl. *pathetic* vor Augen führen, können die Bedeutungen von Leid weit voneinander abweichen. Im Grunde wollte ich darauf hinaus, dass geheucheltes Mitleid zuweilen ironisch als Beleidigung gilt und im Sinne der Raummetaphern quasi *unter Niveau* sein kann, wenn es insb. um Status in der Ständegesellschaft geht.

   Also wenn jemand z. B. ständig wiederholt, wie unsicher die ganze Etymologie ist—zu unsicher um auf *Leid* abzustellen—wird das zuweilen beidigt abgelehnt, weil der Autor hätte ja keine Ahnung worum es geht. Das ist natürlich subjektiv. Und daher sind solche eindimensionalen Modellvorstellungen kaum tragfähig, so dass man das bezeichnete Verhalten gleichwohl *herblassend* nennen kann. In *-b-lass-* liegt denn auch schon ein passender Vergleichswert um die Metapher auszuschlagen.

   *Beleidigen* ist das wahrscheinlich meist gebrauchte Wort der deutschen Sprache für einen umfangreichen Themenkomplex. Wo soll man da bitte schön anfangen? Das ist doch belästigend, wenn jemandend einen Vergleich fordert, diesen jedoch nur einseitig eingeht. Ich kann dir ja mal zeigen, was eine Beleidigung ist.

Um also auf die Frage zurückzukommen:

> Wenn ich Unrecht habe und es nur einen zarten Unterschied gibt, kann ich ihn nicht bemerken — vielleicht könntet Ihr Beispiele dafür geben?

Das klingt absurd, denn das Modalverb engl. *can*, das hier offenbar durchscheint, funktioniert anders als im Deutschen.

Das nennt man dann eine Beleidigung für die Ohren, auch im Sinne der Fragestellung, "Wie seht ihr ..."; mit den Ohren zu sehen ist wiederum eine Beleidigung des guten Geschmacks. Aber Beleidung und Sprache allgemein funktionieren nicht nur auditorisch.

Answer (score -2):

> Du Vollidiot!

Das ist eine Beleidigung. Es wird jemandem ein Schimpfwort an den Kopf geworfen.

> Nicht mal ein Loch in den Schnee pissen kannste!

Das ist hingegen eine richtige Beschimpfung.